# Looking for an old card game called "Kingdom"

Tags: identify-this-game

I know this was an uncommon game when we bought it in the late 1990s or early 2000s, and now I've tried several searches for it, and have come up dry. It's a Bible/Christian themed card game that I think has the word "Kingdom" written on the left edge of each card. I don't think there was any kind of a board associated with it. Anyone have any ideas? I've searched Google, eBay, Google images, and more, to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: What comes to mind would be https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2098/heresy - it would fit the time frame, the theme and mechanic. The full name was Heresy: Kingdom come

Comment: @Zibelas you should write that up as an answer, you can always delete it again if it turns out to be wrong

Comment: @Zibelas, thanks for the suggestion! That's not it but you're spot on about time frame and that it's discontinued. The one I'm looking for was just a card game, I'm 99% sure.